# bbcode : How to draw a table

Tags: forum, bbcode

Is there any way to draw a table in a forum which uses bb code if [Table] tab is not supported ?

The tags being allowed in the forum are :

```
[b], [i], [u]
[color]
[size]
[font]
[highlight]
[left], [right], [center]
[indent]
[email]
[url]
[thread]
[post]
[list]
[img]
[quote]
[noparse]
[attach]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not think so.

But, depending on your purpose, it may be sufficient to force a monotype font (e.g. Courier) using the `[font]` tag, and then simply "draw" your table by hand using ASCII characters. For example:

```
[font=courier]
-----------------
| Col A | Col B |
-----------------
|  1    |   X   |
|  2    |   Y   |
|  3    |   Z   |
-----------------
[/font]
```

Certainly, it is troublesome and may be considered dirty, but your set of available tools is pretty limited.

Answer (score 1):

The [code][/code] tag will maintain white spacing. Example at 
http://www.bbcode.org/examples/?id=15. I can see that [code] tags may not be allowed in your forum but are they truly disabled? If so, is there any possibility of turning them on?

Alternatively, I would try Wojciech Żółtak's idea to use a monospaced font.

Finally, you could take a screen cap of the table and insert it as an image. Include the table text as part of the image's alt and/or title tag.